# Loading Images from Jar file only works on Development Machine?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, embedded-resource, imageicon

I am having trouble loading Images contained within a JAR file. I have read a number of other posts related to this. But cannot find the answer. Now here is where it gets complicated.. This all works fine if I am using a Runnable JAR file exported from Eclipse and Run it using the standard JRE. However This JAR file is actually a plugin for a piece of software called pro/ENGINEER which has it's own JRE that is used to run the JAR file. The strange thing is.. that this works fine on the development machine, that has eclipse installed and so on, but doesn't work on any of the client machines?! But I can't see what is different.

I am trying to load the image using:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("resources/Header.png");
```

This method is called from my 'Start' class, and the Jar is structured as follows:

```
load
  Start.java
      load.resources
           Header.png
```

If I Open the Jar file with WinRar you can see the Image definitely exists in the jar, in this position.

I know this may be a very specific question but if anyone can be of any help that would be great.

Comment: Do you have special characters in the path to the jar file on the machine where it's not working?

Comment: I don't get it, what is `load.resources`?  Is it a single directory named `load.resources` or two directories of structure `load/resources` or..?  What is the completely qualified path and name of the resource (`Header.png`) within the Jar, starting from the root?

Comment: Hello Andrew thanks for the response. load.resources was the package name, so the structure in the jar is load/resources. The code was actually fine, it was an issue with Jlink/ProENGINEER. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the particular problem you're having now, however I ran into the problem of not finding a resource in a JAR file several times in the past.

The solution was to not get the resource from the **class**, but from the **class loader** as demonstrated below:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/Header.png"));
```

Mind the **.getClassLoader()** call after the getClass().

Hope this helps.